# Use XPath to retrieve attribute value for specific attribute

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

In PowerShell I'm trying to retrieve the value of an attribute using XPath. In the example below, I'd like to get the value of "name" for the category of "hi," which would be "new test."

Example code shows:

```xml
<Report name="test" category="thisone">
  <String>test</String>
  <String>test2</String>
  <Report name="new test" category="hi">
    <String>hello</String>
    <String>hi again</String>
  </Report>
</Report>
```

This is what I have:

```bsh
Select-Xml -XPath "//Report[@name='test']/Report" | Select name |
    Out-File "result.txt"
```

My results are:

```
name
----
```

I don't really need to specify the category attribute because that `<Report>` tag will always be right after the first `<Report>` tag, so that's why I thought it would be easier to use XPath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expand the node first. 
Select-XML is providing the object. If you do :

```
Select-Xml -Xml $XML -XPath "//Report[@name='test']/Report"
```

you will get

> Node    : Report
>
> Path    : InputStream
>
> Pattern : //Report[@name='test']/Report

Once you expand "Node" you will get a bunch more properties

```
Select-Xml -Xml $XML -xPath "//Report[@name='test']/Report" | Select-Object –ExpandProperty “node” | select *
```

> name            : new test
>
> category        : hi
>
> String          : {hello, hi again}
>
> LocalName       : Report
>
> ...etc...etc

Full Concept Below

```
[xml]$XML = @"
<Report name="test" category="thisone">
 <String>test</String>
 <String>test2</String>
  <Report name="new test" category="hi">
  <String>hello</String>
  <String>hi again</String>
  </Report>
</Report>
"@

Select-Xml -Xml $XML -xPath "//Report[@name='test']/Report" | Select-Object –ExpandProperty “node” | select name
```

Comment: Perfect that did it! BTW, can I throw that value into a variable, adding something like $hi = before that statement? I'm currently using Out-File to a text file and I see that it writes "name" and "----" then the value underneath, I don't really care about those 2 lines and trying to eliminate them...

Comment: `Select-Xml -Xml $XML -xPath "//Report[@name='test']/Report" | Select-Object –ExpandProperty “node” | foreach-object{$_.name} | Out-file "HELLO.TXT"`

Comment: Nice! That worked as well! Is there a way I can assign it to a variable? I tried and I get this: cmdlet Select-Xml at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Xml[0]:

Comment: I meant to capture the value and assign it to a variable, but no worries, I figured it out already! Thx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

XPath can get the value of an attribute directly.

```
(Select-Xml -Xml $XML -xPath "//Report[@name='test']/Report/@name").Node.Value
```

(But still need to extract the value form the resulting `[XmlAttribute]`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-xpath version:

```
(get-content file.xml) -as 'xml' | foreach { $_.report.report.name }

new test
```

Or another xpath:

```
get-content -raw file.xml | select-xml '//*[@category="hi"]/@name' | 
  % { $_.node.'#text' }

new test
```